# Need xml driven weather component in the intranet

Tags: xml, flash, rss, weather

I want to know if there's a free xml driven weather component (flash or other) to display weather in my intanet site.

All the components I've found use online rss feed.
Is there a component that supports update  in offline mode (manually).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an existing library, but why don't you just create your own RSS feed (it's a simple XML file) and update the data manually?

Comment: But I need a flash object that uses the rss file and displays the weather information.

Comment: You said "All the components I've found use online RSS feed." - There should be one where you can set the url to check for an RSS feed. Just link to your local intranet xml file, and make that look like the online RSS feed.